# Conditional logic in select statement

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2012, sql-server-2008-r2

I have the following query that is working quite well but I encountered some records that I haven't seen before. Instead of `<InstrumentID>` they are `<OriginalInstrumentID>`. I want my query to pick up both. So, if `<InstrumentID>` isn't found, check for and return `<OriginalInstrumentID>` otherwise, `NULL`.

The `<OriginalInstrumentID>` only shows up when the `msg_type` is `ACCTV21`. I'm not sure if I should use a case statement, IF..Then..ELSE, boolean logic.. or anything else. I've been reading so much I'm completely discombobulated. Help. Please.

```
Use Database
DECLARE @First VARCHAR(15), @Second VARCHAR(15)
SET @First = '<InstrumentID>'
SET @Second = '</InstrumentID>'

select *
from 
(
        SELECT out_interface_id, msg_id , 
        SUBSTRING(xml_msg, CHARINDEX(@First, xml_msg) + LEN(@First), 
                 CHARINDEX(@Second, xml_msg) - 
                 CHARINDEX(@First, xml_msg) - 
                 LEN(@First)) as InstrumentID,
        msg_type, xml_msg, CAST(xml_msg AS XML) as [Quick_XML], 
        date_received,status, last_modified, environment,
        transaction_closed_date
        from Table1 
        where msg_type in ('BALMIS','ACCTV21') 
        and date_received >= CAST(GETDATE() -1 as DATE)
        and date_received < CAST(GETDATE() as DATE)
) x
where x.InstrumentID = 'ABC123'
order by date_received desc
```

Comment: You should be doing XML lookups using XPath & XQuery, not manually by searching elements in strings...

Comment: XPath is overkill. I have the same query using XPath but my co-workers don't understand it and, therefore, won't use it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd go for a `CASE` statement in your `SELECT`, something like

```
InstrumentID=
    CASE WHEN CHARINDEX(@First,xml_msg)<>0 -- found <InstrumentId>?
    THEN SUBSTRING(xml_msg, CHARINDEX(@First, xml_msg) + LEN(@First),  -- lookup <InstrumentId>
                 CHARINDEX(@Second, xml_msg) - 
                 CHARINDEX(@First, xml_msg) - 
                 LEN(@First))
    ELSE CASE WHEN msg_type='ACCTV21' AND CHARINDEX('<OriginalInstrumentId>',xml_msg)<>0 -- found <OriginalInstrumentId>?
         THEN -- lookup <OriginalInstrumentId>
         ELSE NULL -- not found any instrument element
         END
    END
```